# Could Tasslehoff Burrfoot have stolen a belt buckle without anyone noticing?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, npc, dragonlance

My uncle had Tasslehoff Burrfoot steal my freind's belt buckle and replace it with string before he could notice. Was this actually reasonably possible for him? What are Tasslehoff Burrfoot's stats?

Comment: If you want stats you should tell us the game you are playing, and which edition. However, if the DM did this, most games allow the DM to tweak the stats of existing characters as he wishes. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: It was a 3.5 d and d conversion of the dragon lance setting. I think it was the original premade story.

Comment: I've revised this to focus on your question -- whether that thing is possible -- because it could have an entirely different answer to "here are his stats", and his stats might not properly convey whether that's possible.

Comment: *Reasonable* is subjective.

Comment: @ShadowKras Yes, but we’re experts here with expert opinions that can be backed up by experience (play experience, rules experience, and so on). Voters can make a judgment on it. I don’t think that makes things *primarily* opinion-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So D&D 3.5e would have a character use the Sleight of Hand skill to attempt to take something unseen, but the only entries indicated are

> DC 20: Lift a small object from a person.

and from the epic usages of the skill,

> DC 50: Lift a sheathed from another creature and hide it on the character’s person, if the weapon is no more than one size category larger than the character’s own size.

Neither of these is a good fit for a belt that someone is wearing: that is not something that can be freely removed, but has to be unbuckled first, while even the epic, DC-50 usage of the skill refers to an item that is freely accessible. The DC-20 usage only specifies that the object is small, and a belt is reasonably considered small, but the fact that it is DC 50 to remove a sheathed weapon (even with the extra bit about hiding it on yourself) suggests to me that something *harder* to steal (a belt) should have a higher DC than 50, not a lower one like 20. The DC-20 usage, in my opinion, would be for pick-pocketing or purse-cutting; actually unbuckling a belt, especially if it then has to be fed through loops in pants, is beyond a DC 20 by a large margin.

(DC 20 would *not* be hard for a thief of Tasslehoff’s purported skills.)

Beyond that issue, there is also the issue of replacing the string: the rules don’t offer *anything* for that. In fact, considering the possibility of placing a cursed item on someone else, it would be wise to *adamantly refuse* to allow that sort of thing. The DC would certainly be quite high, higher even than discussed above in all likelihood.

So the game does not really suggest that this is possible, and if it is possible, it would suggest a very difficult check for doing it. I do not know Tasslehoff Burrfoot’s stats, but he is not an epic character, which would make this very unlikely to work for him.

But more than likely your uncle was just fiating it because he thought it was cool and/or funny. It also follows the Dragonlance books, where Tasslehoff Burrfoot was constantly stealing. Your mileage may vary on how cool and/or funny this all is, but for what it’s worth, my opinion is that Tasslehoff and really the entire kender race are very much anathema to the very concepts of cool or fun, and reasons in and of themselves to avoid playing in Dragonlance in the first place. But since you agreed to play Dragonlance, the DM has a fairly reasonable claim to this being what you signed up for.

Comment: Arent coin purses normally tied to a belt or something like that? I think that part of using the Sleight of Hand skill involves removing the object from the target. No object is normally just *there* on your body, maybe hats.

Comment: The rules cover swiping the belt buckle adequately, but to "replace it with string" potentially takes things to a whole 'nother level: for example, force-equipping cursed magic items onto unsuspecting creatures. Anyway, that part'd be *my* big concern were a DM to try this on my PC.

Comment: This is probably your Uncle going with Rule of Storytelling. In all the books featuring him, Tass can steal _almost anything_ without _anyone_ noticing, including himself (Tass often ended up with pouches full of stuff he had no recollection of acquiring). In fact, the only person who could reliably defend themselves against Tass's wandering hands was Raistlin...and then, he could only really protect his pouch of spell components and spellbook.

Comment: @ShadowKras I understand it to refer to picking a pocket, maybe purse cutting. Unbuckling a belt and pulling it through the loops on pants is a lot. If it’s just cinched around the waist, easier, but still a big deal. The string, as HeyICanChan says, is also a big deal. Will update the answer.

Comment: @guildsbounty Yup, which really IMO is a pretty telling indicator of the overall quality of the Dragonlance novels and their suitability as a setting for games...

Comment: (Several *YouTube* videos show pickpockets swiping someone's belt, but none I could find show a pickpocket subsequently *replacing* the belt! As an aside, IIRC, one famous and *extremely* professional sleight of hand artist (who figured he had about a 50/50 shot at stealing a mark's glasses *while the glasses were still on the mark's face*) was considered *so good* that, when the President took a trip to Vegas, the Secret Service sent the artist a letter (that he kept) forbidding him from approaching the President.)

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, if the story demands it

I assume here that your uncle is the GM.

A good story does not always have to conform exactly to game stats. Since Tass is a "legendary" character, that he do something out of the ordinary is perfectly fine and in line with his character.

Can (or should) he do it over and over? No. That he pulls it off once is a testament to his skills. That he does it all the time is a weak plot.

Can that lead to more adventure? Most likely, see where it goes rather than get hung up on the game math.

Did that seriously impact your friend? It does not seem like it.

Should all kender be killed on-sight? Yes.

As for Tass's stats, that is a question that has multiple answers... Tass from the early stories and Tass from later stories is a much different character. Not knowing that makes it impossible to answer.

Therefore, I would let it go. See where it goes. If it happens too much, then tell the GM that it is not fun. Having your stuff stolen by a character of legend? That's cool to me.

Answer (score -1):

Tasslehoff Burrfoot (2nd Edition - AD&D)
Kender Thief (Handler)
Level: 12 
Str: 13 
Dex: 16 
Con: 14 
Alignment: NG
Int: 9 
Wis: 12 
Cha: 11

its the wrong edition but i cant see the stats varry to much, that said on pure stats alone baring that it was some magic, there is no way he could have done that. regardless of the edition tas has never been stated to be an epic level character which he would need to be for this to be even remotly possible

Comment: This does not answer the main question, which is about whether he could do the thing.

Comment: @Erik The question states “What are Tasslehoff Burrfoot's stats?” This may not answer the title, but it answers the body.

Comment: i was unaware that someone changed the title, it previously asked for stats

Comment: It was asking for stats in order to figure out whether a thing was possible, yeah. I reframed it to ask whether the thing was possible. So both the title and question text were revised. Sorry if this was pulling the rug out from under you, maybe the revision I made wasn't proper.

Comment: Regardless of whether the question asks for his stats or not, the question is tagged 3.5 so offering his 2e stats isn’t a great answer.

Comment: i think he was asking if the feat was possible based on his stats, in D&D you could manage tht in a number of ways, i think he was expecting an ungodly high dex for slight of hand or something along those lines

Comment: Note that you have an opportunity now to [edit] the answer to help the more detailed question. It's likely to gather more downvotes as it's currently written.

Answer (score -2):

As RAW, no.  As @KRyan pointed out, there are no rules to do such a thing.

As RAI, why not?  Find the DC from an equally hard task and make the roll.

My biggest problem is that Tasslehoff **wouldn't** do it.  He didn't see himself as a thief.  He would pick up things that caught his eye as a momentary impulse.  To replace it with something else to cover what he had done implies that he thought that there would be consequences to taking the belt buckle.

If he didn't like someone, he wouldn't express that feeling in a passive aggressive swipe and replace, he would be vocal about it; very vocal.

Remember, Kender do not have fear.  They do not hide their feelings.  They are child like.  They are innocent (just ask them).  And **they do not leave anything where you put it** (the annoying little twerps)!

I know.  I played a Kender much to the amusement and annoyance of our group.